# Real-time dashboard with Excel

Tags: excel, vba, automation, dashboard

I'm working on building a dashboard for some of the higher-ups in my organization. The dashboard uses the information stored in Excel files made by several separate departments. The goal of the project is to automatically sync all of the separate Excel files and put them together to provide context. Then, take the information from the files to create a **real-time** performance dashboard.

What would be the best approach to do this? Is there a way to do this within Excel?

Comment: How often does this get updated? Also, can you explain what you mean by "real-time".  (Generally, real-time output  has real-time input.  How many data sources (departments) are there? How are these files getting to you?

Comment: @ashleedawg is right. how do you define "real-time"? you have to keep in mind that a high refresh rate means a high workload. It is theoretically possible to do that, but I think you will need some workarounds...

Comment: Also, with no idea about your organization or what kind/quantity/quality of data you intend to report real-time, its impossible to give any advice. When I think realtime dashboard, I think back to a company I worked for as part of an 8-person team of Realtime Analysts. The software we used likely cost a hundred grand. With the information you provided I have no way to tell if your scope is like that, or maybe more akin to a sign-in sheet.

Comment: Just triggered my memory, one of the apps we used was [Crystal Reports]( https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_Reports) for real time connections to and from several platforms including MS Office. Reporting complex metrics on 5000+ employees worldwide, that required split-second decision  making, we outgrew it but perhaps Crystal's the kind of tool you should look into.